# How to render translated node body in two languages?

Tags: 7, nodes, hooks, i18n-l10n

I use entity_translation to translate node body field, so in a fully loaded node object `body` is an array of 2 languages ('en' and 'ru').

For specific node type I would like to render body in both languages one after another:

> Russian version of node body
>
> English version of node body

so switching between translations will not be needed.

What hook can I use to achieve this?

In implementation of `hook_node_load()` body is an array of 2 languages, but in `hook_node_view_alter()` body already contains only the current language value.

When using `node_load()` in `hook_preprocess_node`, it retrieves the node object from cache and its body has only one (current) language value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution: call `field_attach_view` with the required language.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_node().
 */
function MYMODULE_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  if ($GLOBALS['language']->language == 'ru') {
    $original_langcode = 'en';
    $content_original = field_attach_view('node', $vars['node'], $vars['view_mode'], $original_langcode);

    // need to check if languages match, it may be a language fallback
    if ($content_original['body']['#language'] == $original_langcode) {
      $vars['content']['body_original'] = $content_original['body']
    }
  }
}
```